# how to full-page section scroll website without using full-page javascript (&) how to add horizontal and vertical slider in section

Tags: fullpage.js

```
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html#firstPage/1


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">
        </div>
        <div class="slide"><h1>Slide 1.2</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1>Slide 1.3</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section"><h1>Section 2</h1></div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide"><h1>Section 3</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1>Slide 3.2</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1>Slide 3.3</h1></div>
        <div class="slide"><h1>Slide 3.4</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section"><h1>Section 4</h1></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="_4" value="3" />
</body>
</html>
```

same like this
This is the example code for full-page js
how to create without using full-page js packagges
same like this
This is the example code for full-page js
how to create without using full-page js packagges
same like this
This is the example code for full-page js
how to create without using full-page js packagges

Comment: Why don't you want to use fullPage.js? THat's the whole purpose of a library, saving you a great number of headaches and time.